# iOS: listener of the "hide" button in the keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField
```

to remove the keyboard when the user click on the return or done button and it works perfectly. My problem is that when my application is in the landscape mode or when I run it in the iPad, the "hide" button is added in the keyboard (the button displayed in the picture). When I click it, the keyboard is hided but the `textFieldShouldReturn` is never called.

How can I detect when this button is tapped?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receiving Keyboard Notifications
When the keyboard is shown or hidden, iOS sends out the following notifications to any registered observers:

- **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification**
- **UIKeyboardDidShowNotification**
- **UIKeyboardWillHideNotification**
- **UIKeyboardDidHideNotification**

you can get the detail information from [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

for e.g

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardhideHandle:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];



- (void) keyboardhideHandle:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"you received the action here");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To detect when the keyboard from a UITextField is being brought up we could setup the observers in viewDidLoad, like this for example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// setup keyboard observers
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardCameUp:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWentAway:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

These observers will call a method in our class (using @selector). Mine are called keyboardCameUp and keyboardWentAway:

```
- (void)keyboardCameUp:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"Keyboard came up!");
}

- (void)keyboardWentAway:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"Keyboard went away!");
}
```

src: e.g. http://pinkstone.co.uk